# Mongoose - update filtered reference id without race condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have two mongoose schema such as

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    pet: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pet'}
})

Users = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
PetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String}
})
Pets = mongoose.model('Pet', UserSchema)
```

I want to do something like

`UPDATE Users SET PET=(SELECT _id FROM Pets WHERE name=petname) where name=username`

It is possible to do with 2 steps as below.

1. find _id where name=petname from Pets collection.
2. update pet where name=username from Users collection.

Since between step 1 and step 2, pets can be deleted, so I want to query with a single mongoose query. How can I achieve this with a single Query object?

Comment: mongodb is only really atomic at a document level. Do pets need to be a separate collection? Can they be embedded as a [sub document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)? 4.2+ replicasets can have [transactions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) now, but I don't think that helps this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The only query I'm aware of that allows to do such thing is combination of `aggregate` + `forEach`. For example:

```
Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Pets',
      localField: 'petname',
      foreignField: 'name',
      as: 'pets'
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
  Pets.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { name: doc.pets[0].petname } });
});
```

But this would update correctly only if your `join` operation returns only one joined document. If `UPDATE Users SET PET=(SELECT _id FROM Pets WHERE name=petname) where name=username` subquery returns only one document, then this solution should work for you.